# lib.dom.d.ts lacks lots of stuff

Tags: typescript, dom

is there any improved `lib.dom.d.ts`? The default one lacks so much stuff, it's annoying to see all the compilation errors.

E.g. this line:

`window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob`

has already 3 errors (only `Blob` is defined)

Answer (score 0):

There is already an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28525) in the TypeScript repository that even links back to other SO questions.

Looking at [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts), `Blob` is already defined on `interface Window`, and `File`/`FileList` are at least defined.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at `lib.dom.d.ts`, it seems they're all fully defined... wonder why OP is getting errors.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts For `Blob`, yes it's on `Window`, but not `File` and `FileList`.

Comment: In that case, maybe I shouldn't have deleted my comment about using [`lib.webworker.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/40bd7c89abbdf79493e2ea20dd80d9eb657dc82e/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts)